# How to convert a type from nullable to non-nullable in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, generics, nullable, non-nullable

Right now, I have nullable generic type and I can check if it is nullable or not. However, I cannot find a way to get a non-nullable type from it. Here is what I want to do:

```
If Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(nullableType) IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim nonNullableType As Type = GetNonNullableType(nullableType)
End if
```

For example, if nullableType is Date?, I want "GetNonNullableType" function to return Date. If it is Integer?, the function will return Integer.

Comment: Are you talking about `Type` or `Value`? `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` will return underlying type (If Date? - return Date). Why you cannot use it?

Comment: Ah. Thank you for pointing out. I just don't really know how this function works. The reason I know the way how to check if it is null or not because I just searched through the internet and copy to my code. You can downvote my stupid question -_-"

Answer (score -1):

From Fabio suggestion, I can also Nullable.GetUnderlyingType function to get non-nullable type so it will be:

```
Dim nonNullableType As Type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(nullableType)
```